# Difference between JavaScript's trimLeft() vs trimStart()

Tags: javascript

What's the difference between JavaScript's `trimLeft()` and `trimStart()` methods? How does `trimLeft()` work with right-to-left scripts?

Comment: nothing ... see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trimStart and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trimLeft - trust me, they are two different URLs but note how the latter redirects to the former

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `trimStart()` method removes `whitespace` from the beginning of a string. `trimLeft()` is an alias of this method.

So both work same both return the same value. The example of proof is attached.

```js
var greeting = "   Hello world!   ";

console.log(greeting);
// expected output: "   Hello world!   ";

console.log("output:" + greeting.trimStart() + ";", "output:" + greeting.trimLeft() + ";");
// expected output: "Hello world!   ";

console.log(greeting.trimStart() === greeting.trimLeft());
// expected output: true;
```

Answer (score 8):

MDN states that `trimLeft` is an [alias](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trimStart) of `trimStart`.

Answer (score 4):

> The property `trimStart` is preferred. The `trimLeft` property is provided principally for compatibility with old code. It is recommended that the `trimStart` property be used in **new ECMAScript** code.

However, `trimLeft()` or `trimStart()` do not affect the value of the string itself.

```js
var greeting = "   Hello world!   ";

console.log(greeting);
// expected output: "   Hello world!   ";

console.log("trimStart:" + greeting.trimStart() + ";"); console.log("trimLeft:" + greeting.trimLeft() + ";");
// expected output: "Hello world!   ";


var nTrimVal = greeting.trimStart();
var nTrimNormal = "   Hello world!   ".trim();
console.log("Original String: ", greeting);
console.log("String value and new Trim value is same: ", greeting == nTrimVal);
```

Answer (score 4):

The existing answers are correct that `trimStart` and `trimLeft` are aliases and therefore functionally identical.  However, support varies.  [ES2019](https://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/) was the first version to specify [`trimStart`](https://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-string.prototype.trimstart) and [`trimLeft`](https://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#String.prototype.trimleft) , with the note:

> The property `trimStart` is preferred. The `trimLeft` property is provided principally for compatibility with old code. It is recommended that the `trimStart` property be used in new ECMAScript code.

The rationale for preferring the name `trimStart` over `trimLeft` [is consistency with `padStart`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-string-left-right-trim/#rationale).  `trimLeft` is much more widely supported (Edge, Node < 10, Firefox < 61, Chrome < 66) (via [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trimstart#Browser_compatibility) and [kangax](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/#test-string_trimming)).  The choice of which to use is one of compatibility vs consistency.

Answer (score 1):

I got an error when I used `trimStart` on Edge

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'trimStart'
```

`trimLeft` works  well

Edge version:

```
Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically both `trimStart()` and `trimLeft()` are used for the same purpose to remove the left white spaces from a provided string `trimEnd()` and `trimRight()` are used to remove left whitespaces from the strings. They can be called as aliases to each other.

For example:

```
const dedent = (s:string) => s.split('\n').map( l => l.trimLeft() ).join('\n') ;
```

Answer (score 0):

both are exactly same functions but with different names or in short alias 
this is the proof:

```js
console.log( String.prototype.trimLeft === String.prototype.trimStart );
```